# Matching 2d coordinates with 3d ones

Tags: 3d, 2d, coordinates, match

I'm trying to find how can i **match x,y coordinates of a 2d image** with the **x,y coordinates** of a **3d image**. Does anyone know how i can do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to know the parameters of the camera (camera calibration will provide them). The trick (given the lack of info in your question) is to follow features in your image that can be 'paired' with the very same features in your 3D model. Then you need to use a PnP (pose and position estimation algorithm) to retrieve the complete mapping between your 'paired' or matched features. I will recommend you read more into SIFT and SURF and the openCV project.